# 'a' is an array, its content is its address, the address of a[0] is also the address of 'a', yet the content of a[0] is not the address of 'a', how?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

PLEASE help I'm tearing my hair out! Does C not know how to print the correct addresses or what? and if that's the case do we just ignore it? I've explained everything in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {0xA, 0xB};


    printf("%p", &a);   printf("  <---address of 'a'\n");

    printf("0000000000%X", a);   printf("  <---content of 'a'\n");

    printf("%p", &a[0]); printf("  <---address of a[0]\n");

    printf("000000000000000%X", a[0]);   printf("  <---yet the content of a[0] is not the same as the content of 'a' despite sharing the same memory location\n\n");


    return 0;
}
```

I tried with a regular pointer and its content is an address, its address? a different address. I'm afraid that my foundational understanding of pointers is wrong. Thank you in advance

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Given `int[] a`, `a` (due to array decay) and `&a[0]` evaluate to the address of the same object.

Comment: That is, `a == &a[0]`. Updating the output messages (and corresponding formatting) with that information (and likewise updating the `&a` and `a[0]` cases) might reduce some confusion and expose a more refined question.

Comment: Although, as has been commented and answered, `a == &a[0]`, you won't necessarily see the same thing when you printf that using the (incorrect) format conversion `%X`. On a little-endian platform with 64-bit addresses and 32-bit integers, `%X` will most likely only print the low order 32 bits of the address of `a`. For additional confusion, it will print the hex digits in upper-case, although `%p` may print them in lower-case. Also `00000000000%X` is a bit odd. Use `%016X` if you want the conversion to be printed with precisely 16 digits. `%16X` would insert leading spaces.

Comment: ... Of course, printing a pointer using an integer format conversion code is Undefined Behaviour. So it might do anything. You should request and respect the compiler warnings. I'm only indicating what you're *likely* to see on common platforms.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an array, not a pointer. Arrays are not pointers.

In `printf("%p", &a);`, `&a` is the address of the array. Properly, this should be printed by converting it to `void *`, as with `printf("%p", (void *) &a);`.

In `printf("0000000000%X", a);`, `a` is automatically converted to the address of the first element of `a`. Since this is an address (a pointer in C), it should be printed with `%p`, not `%X`, and also should be converted to `void *`. Printing it with `%X` can cause various problems. Once printed correctly, the address is generally the same as that for `&a`, because the array and its first element start at the same place in memory (since the latter is the first part of the former).

This automatic conversion of an array to the address of its first element whenever an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof`, as the operand of unary `&`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array (in a declaration).

In `printf("%p", &a[0]);`, `&a[0]` is the address of the first element of `a`, effectively the same as `a` in the prior code.

In `printf("000000000000000%X", a[0]);`, `a[0]` is the value of the first element of `a`. `%X` is a technically incorrect format for this, as it is for `unsigned int`, whereas `a[0]` is `int`, but the value will commonly be printed anyway, reinterpreted as an `unsigned int`. Since this is the value of an element, not an address, it naturally differs from the prior outputs.